# EXT4 filesystem data loss running Debian 9 under KVM

Tags: debian, kvm-virtualization, ext4

I'm trying to setup KVM virtualization on a CentOS 7.6.1810 host. This is a machine with a Xeon E-2176G  CPU and a double 1 TB SSD drive. The SSDs are configured as software raid.

```
Personalities : [raid1]
md126 : active raid1 sdb3[0] sda3[1]
      828441920 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/7 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md127 : active raid1 sdb1[1] sda1[0]
      104856576 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/1 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk
```

The SSD has a boot/root and swap partition, the additional space is a LVM volume create on top of the raid volume for virtual machine storage.

Fdisk output:

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   209848319   104923136   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2       209848320   218236927     4194304   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3       218236928  1875385007   828574040   fd  Linux raid autodetect
```

vgdisplay output:

```
 --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vps
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  95
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                0
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               790.00 GiB
  PE Size               128.00 MiB
  Total PE              6320
  Alloc PE / Size       0 / 0
  Free  PE / Size       6320 / 790.00 GiB
  VG UUID               4jp2up-3ZDd-5zVb-2ZvC-SvC5-qwte-iXmSTt
```

I'm using SolusVM to deploy KVM templates which I create myself from using the net install ISO from Debian. All seems to go well but as the machine is booted and I/O load increases the file system gets corrupted.

I test this by doing:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/test1.img bs=1G count=1 oflag=dsync
```

Then the command is aborted and the logfile/dmesg shows this.

```
[   77.921283] EXT4-fs error (device vda1): ext4_validate_block_bitmap:386: comm kworker/u2:1: bg 11: bad block bitmap checksum
[   77.968478] EXT4-fs (vda1): Delayed block allocation failed for inode 524302 at logical offset 165888 with max blocks 2048 with error 74
[   77.968573] EXT4-fs (vda1): This should not happen!! Data will be lost

[   77.970041] EXT4-fs error (device vda1): ext4_validate_block_bitmap:386: comm kworker/u2:1: bg 12: bad block bitmap checksum
[   77.971194] EXT4-fs error (device vda1): ext4_validate_block_bitmap:386: comm kworker/u2:1: bg 13: bad block bitmap checksum
[   77.972094] EXT4-fs error (device vda1): ext4_validate_block_bitmap:386: comm kworker/u2:1: bg 14: bad block bitmap checksum
[   78.342607] EXT4-fs error (device vda1): ext4_validate_block_bitmap:386: comm dd: bg 18: bad block bitmap checksum
[   78.490468] EXT4-fs (vda1): Delayed block allocation failed for inode 524302 at logical offset 231424 with max blocks 2048 with error 74
[   78.490563] EXT4-fs (vda1): This should not happen!! Data will be lost
```

Now normally, you would think of a hardware failure, however:

- I have 3 similar hosts all brand new hardware all with exactly the same issue.
- Only Debian 9 has the issue, CentOS as guest VM on EXT4 is fine.
- Switching Debian 9 to EXT3 instead of EXT4 solves the issue.
- This only happens under heavy I/O load.

I prefer to have EXT4 though. Any idea what could cause this? I'm obv. using the latest Debian 9.9 with kernel:

```
Linux debian9 4.9.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.168-1+deb9u3 (2019-06-16) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'm working on this for 5 days now but I can't seem to find the solution. I only found this:

https://access.redhat.com/articles/41313

But I'm not sure it describes my issue, however option 3 seems a workaround for me. My disks are alligned though and I def. don't use AIO=native.

Hope somebody has a clue!

Comment: How is the virtual storage set up on the host? You showed a volume group, but it contains no data.

Answer (score 1):

Well in the end I solved it myself, I don't know how it's related but in case anyone else faces the same issue.

I changed my fstab from:

```
/dev/vda1         /               ext4    defaults      1   1
```

to:

```
/dev/vda1         /               ext4    defaults      0   1
```

And for some reason that solved the issue. I found it by trying a public KVM template from someone else which didn't have the issue and had its fstab like this.